# Why my class field is still pointing null after the initialisation?

Tags: java, class, nullpointerexception

I have a Java NullPointerException Question.

For instance: 
I have three classes A, B and C.

```
public class A
{
    public void methodA1()
    {    }
}
//////////////////////////////
public class B
{
    private A a;
    private C c;

    public void methodB1()
    {
        a = c.methodC1;
    }

    public void methodB2()
    {
        a.methodA1();
    }
}
/////////////////////////////
public class C
{

  public A methodC1()
  {
       return new A();
  }
}
```

As you can see the code above, the main issues is in the Class B. My question is, if the field a in the class B is initilised in the methodB1, why I cannot use a again in the methodB2? compiler is giving me the NullPointerException for using the code a.methodeA1(). And I cannot create another new a again as I need the results from the methodB1(), namely the a in the methodB1(). Any help, please.

Comment: How does this line compile with no semicolon: `a = c.methodC1` In addition, you have not posted enough code such that someone else could take the code, compile it, run it and see the same problem you are.

Comment: the line `a = c.methodC1` does indeed not have a semi-colon, and isn't it supposed to evaluate methodC1, i.e. `a = c.methodC1();`?

Comment: in the Class C there is a methodC1 and it creates a new A and returns it. It would be too long to supply the code which would compile. My main question is that if a field of a class is initialised in a method in that class, can it be used in another method. In my case, the line a.methodA1() inthe methodB2 is giving me nullpointerexception.

Comment: @Dilshat Abduwalli I disagree with "It would be too long to supply the code which would compile.". Just write a simple example that demonstrates the technique you can't get to work, it doesn't have to be the program you observed the problem in, just a simple example that compiles but fails at run time.

Comment: you create reference for c but u didn't initialize the object like C c=new C();

Comment: c = new C() was done outside of the method so I have omitted it. the problem is in the line a.methodA1();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create an object of `C` class but you forget to assign it to a new Object

```
public class B
{
    private A a;
    private C c;

    public void methodB1()
    {
        c = new C(); // Added 
        a = c.methodC1(); // the problem was here  
    }

    public void methodB2()
    {
        a.methodA1();
    }
}
```

You may probably want to read about [NullPointerException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html).

Inside your *constructor*  you must firstly call `methodB1()` like this :

```
    public B(){
    this.methodB1();
    this.methodB2();
    }

    public static void main(String...args){
      new B();
     }
```

Because of avoiding *NullPointerException* of `a`, as you see inside *methodB1* you assign a new object ot `a`.

Comment: I might have been unable to demonstrate the point. c = new C() was done outside of the methodB1() somewhere which makes c.methodC1() running. my problem is a.methodA1() which is giving me a nullpointerexception. so a = c.methodC1() did not give me exception. I thought a.methodA1(); would run as it was done in the above method

Answer (score 1):

There is **no guarantee** that `methodB1()` will be called **before** `methodB2()` - both are public methods, any other class could make use of `methodB2()` before `methodB1()` has initialized `a`.

If you *really* wanted to leave these as two public methods, and you *really* didn't want to initialize `a` or `c` unless one of your class B methods is called. you could instead try this:

```
public class B{
    private A a;
    private C c;

    public void methodB1(){
        if(c == null){
            methodB3();
        }
        a = c.methodC1;
    }

    public void methodB2(){
        if(a == null){
            methodB1();
        }
        a.methodA1();
    }

    public void methodB3(){//Allows other classes to initialize c directly
        c = new C();       //though 'c' is still private so can only be accessed
    }                      //by methodB1()
}
```

Unless `a` and/or `c` are very "expensive" to create (i.e. take up a lot of time, system resources etc), its usually going to be way easier to just make sure you've initialized the variables when you declared them.

I'd recommend reading this nice article on how variables are initialized: http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/initializationP.html

Answer (score 0):

`a= c.method1;` wont initialize it. You are calling a method, code should be

```
c= new C();    
a=c.method1();
```

Comment: True, but this is not the problem here.

Comment: Well that was the problem in the code, the reason why the `method1()` was not being called.

Comment: Just adding the paranthesis did not fix it. Creating a `C` instance first, like you are doing now, will though.

Comment: the problem is in the method B2 not in the B1 for ease I have omitted other codes in the B1. My question was I have initialised a field in one method, can I use that field in another method without initialising again.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have some typo in above code as Patashu has suggested.

This is how class B goes:

```
public class B
```

{

```
private A a;
private C c;

public static void main(String []a)
{
    B b=new B();
    b.methodB1();
    b.methodB2();
}

public void methodB1()
{
    c= new C();
    a = c.methodC1();
    System.out.println("Inside Method B1");
}

public void methodB2()
{
    a.methodA1();
    System.out.println("Inside Method B2");
}
```

}

//////////////////////////////////////////
This is class A:

```
  public class A
{

   public void methodA1()
    {  
      System.out.println("This is class A");  
    }
}
```

and this is working absolutely fine with my JVM... May be there could be issue with the JVM? Not sure! But the above code is working absolutely fine.

Comment: Ok in this case the a.methodeA1() is throwing an nullpointer exception

Comment: I think you should try reinstalling the JAVA. May be some times it's the issue with the JVM, because the above code is working absolutely fine at my machine.